# R flextable as_image (how to insert external image into flextable, how define an image path)

Tags: r, display, flextable

I have an issue with inserting image into flextable. 
Creating flextable and saving it in pptx works fine. But image don't show up. 
Please have a look at the code and point to the error. 
I think I have issue with the path to the image. It needs to the be an external image saved as png in specific fo, not in R.home() 
Idea is to insert red_up.png image which is an red arrow if the Value is above 1.

```
final <- flextable(as.data.frame(final))

img.file <file.path("C:\\Users\\People\\Desktop\\Data_R\\Reporting\\red_up.png")
final <- display(final, i = ~ Value >1, col_key="Apr", 
                 pattern = "{{signal_sign}}", 
                 formatters = list(signal_sign ~ as_image(Apr, src = img.file, width=0.2, height=0.15)))
```

Thank you

Comment: No worries, figured out. I added file path as a full test, just needed to split it into: "C:", "Users", "People", etc.

Comment: It turns out that PowerPoint don't handle well the images entered into flextable. I found a work around and used magick package to insert the images I wanted